# 'noarch binary' on ARM architecture with android

Tags: linux, binary, x86, arm

This is my knowledge:

There are different architectures: x86,x64,arm, and so on(you can find others on wikipedia)
There are different linux binaries for each: x86 - i386,x64 - amd64, arm - armel,armhf).

and there are 'noarch' binaries.

I need to know if 'noarch' binary can run on ARM platform. 
Please correct me if I am wrong and please do correct me,   rather marking question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"noarch" binaries are written in an architecture-independent format. They include but are not limited to shell scripts, Mono/.NET executables, Java classes and jars, and Python scripts. As long as the appropriate interpreter and/or VM is available on the architecture they can be run.

Note that this does not guarantee that the platform they're being run on will support all APIs required for proper execution, just that if they are there then they will run.

Comment: what about my second question?

Comment: The second is a huge question in its own right. I don't understand why you thought it would be a good thing to slap onto the main question.

Comment: Because, there are lot of answers across the web but no one can give me specifics...here[link](http://elinux.org/RPi_Linaro_GCC_Compilation)..this i found most useful tutorial, but is is for older version and for raspberry pi, i want something specific to my device or any arm based android device...not complete tutorial, but at least a hint what those options do in crosstool-ng? or is there other method? i am trying to port a big software with jars and lots of binary libs.

Comment: I thought noarch is one way to go, but it may not work

Comment: I removed second question to raise new one. Thanks!